# Where are the pickup weapons in Battlefield 4?

Tags: battlefield-4

I've played a good bit of Battlefield 4, and used a number of the pickup weapons to good effect, but when browsing through the weapons list, I came across 2 I've never seen: the **USAS-12 FLIR** and the **AMR-2 CQB**. I've found the standard version of the USAS-12 on a number of maps, and the standard and MID versions of the AMR-2, but not these.

Can anyone tell me on which *multiplayer* maps and where they are located? Or provide a reference that tells where all (multiplayer) pickup weapons are in-game?

Comment: Singleplayer or multiplayer, or both?

Comment: Ah, Multiplayer. My bad. I'm not sure that those two particular weapons are in SP though

Comment: I wasn't sure either, but helps clarify the question.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a complete list currently. I know there are pickup weapons in Conquest, Rush, and Obliteration modes on all maps including the China Rising Expansions. I have not seen the two weapons listed on any map, only in the Test Range.

Comment: Well sounds like a complete list would be a good answer to the question then :)

Comment: I've picked up the USAS-12 FLIR before, I can't remember where, but I think it was either in Operation Locker under the tower (C flag in CQ) or in Zavod 311, in the two factory type buildings in the middle you can go into a basement area that connects them.  Next time I play I can try to check this out.  If you want to try the weapons, go into the Test Range, they're all available for pick up/use on the firing range part.

Answer (score 1):

#### USAS-12 FLIR

The **USAS-12 FLIR** is located in the middle of **Operation Locker**, in most game modes objective C: Panopticon. This is were the tower is. The USAS is located on the lower level, on the west side of the tower. I've made a small demonstration video (Vid-1) in which you can see it exacts whereabouts.

*Vid-1: The location of the USAS-12 FLIR on Operation Locker and a little demonstration of its power:*

#### AMR-2 CQB

I believe the **AMR-2 CQB** is on **Pearl Market**, on the top-level of the central building block, where in most gamemodes an objective is located.